# Laravel - restful api

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication

I'm using the laravel framework. In my case, I need to save the data (login or register for example) in remote database on cloud. 
But the communications with database and laravel, **I need to use a rest api.**

I have a php class in laravel with functions (login function for example) and in this function I have created the connection logic to my remote rest API (send email and password).

Now, I made connection to remote database and check if the email and password exists and return back a message (if true then I return the view, false i show a error message).

Till this it works fine. But I have a problem. Because I am **not using the laravel authentication** mechanism in routes file. I am unable to use the middleware to prevent direct access to routes without login. What is the best way to add this security?

I need your help. Thanks a lot.

Regards

Comment: If what you mean is RESTful and stateless, check out https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: If however, you want it to be restful and stateful, you may use Laravel existing authentication and just send the session and csrf headers in each request

Comment: Laravel <-> my remote Rest API <-> my remote Database

In this case it is possivel to use laravel authentication? I only use laravel to get the request from inputs (login for example) and send the request to my remote rest api and this api connect to remote database to save the data.

Comment: Don't understand what Laravel is doing then? If your remote API is doing all the heavy lifting why do you have Laravel in the middle? Some more info would be helpful to understand your problem

Comment: For example to login, when i click in button login i send the request (mail and password) to function in class that i create. In this function and connect to remote rest  api, the remote rest api connect to remote data base, check if the user exist and if it exist return true. In my php function i receive the return from rest api and if it is true e return the view

Comment: Okay so if authentication is happening at remote api, then you probably dont need Laravel for auth

Comment: I use laravel because in first i dont need the rest api, only one remote database. But now i need a rest api to communicate to my database and i'm looking if it is possible using laravel

Comment: Yes, i dont need Laravel for auth, but i need to prevent direct access to my routes

Comment: Yes, in that case get rid of the rest api. Laravel has full support to interact with remote databases. You can have Laravel as the rest API. Question still remains - do you want stateful auth or stateless auth? If stateful, out of the box authentication works well, otherwise use jwt-auth library

Comment: i really need the rest. Because i will made a website that use this database but in future my client and his client can use the same database too and made for example other tool (in java, c#, etc but using always the same database). In this case i can not give direct access (for security reasons), so the solution is using one rest api. In this case the clients only access with get and post commands to my rest and never have direct access to my database. Do you understand now? :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to create a local useraccount, with the credentials of the account recieved from the API. On this way, you can load all the needed data in your website and also use the auth middleware.

There are multiple ways to do so, maybe you can create your own cookie and check it before any output.

Comment: You can simply use the Laravel authentication, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication - also you can take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database so you can get a fresh start for adding own users into the database, on that way you still can use middleware.

Comment: But in this case i need to create a local database to save the users that came from my remote database with my rest api?

Comment: Yes, that is how I did it, last time with the same problem. Otherwise you can create your own cookies and database. But, to remember a user you can create youw local database.

Comment: So when i register an user in my web site for example i need to save in local database on users table and send too my rest api and save in my remote database?

Comment: On that way, you can also use the auth middleware for perfect security and authentication.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. So for this case, this is the only solution that exist?

Comment: I explain to the other user but i will explain to you.. i really need the rest. Because i will made a website that use this database but in future my client and his clients can use the same database too and made for example other tool (in java, c#, etc but using always the same database). In this case i can not give direct access (for security reasons), so the solution is using one rest api. In this case the clients only access with get and post commands to my rest and never have direct access to my database. Do you understand now? :)